# how to access map values and keys stored in a data frame in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

i have a table which description is as follows:

```
# col_name              data_type               comment             

id                      string                                      
persona_model           map<string,struct<score:double,tag:string>>                     

# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             

process_date            string
```

sample row would be something like this(tab separated):

```
000000E91010441BB122402A45D439E7        {"Tech":{"score":0.21678,"tag":"OTHERS"}}    2018-05-16-01
```

Now I want to form another table with only 2 columns `id` and its respective `score` in it. 
How can i do it in scala spark?

Moreover, whats really bugging me is how can I access only a particular `score` and how can I store it in an integer variable lets say `temp`?

Comment: explode the map, select score from struct

Comment: can you provide with sample input, expected output and what you've tried?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan i have edited and added an example, i want to store that score 0.21278 inside a variable integer temp what to do? and also i also want to create a new table which contains those all ids and scores. please help

Comment: can you format the input data according to the table format?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan its actually formatted according to the table format , 1st line of sample row indicated id , 2nd row indicates the persona_model, and the 3rd row indicates process_date

Comment: so you are saying the data has sepeate lines for each columns?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan no ! they are tab seperated , i just changed tab to new line so it would be easier for u to understand

Comment: it would be more helpful if you share the sample dataframe and its schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
val newDF = oldDF.select(col("id"), col("persona_model")("Tech")("score").as("temp"))
```

then you can extract *temp* values easily.

**update**: if you have more than one Key then the procedure is a little more complex.

first create a class for the struct (necesary for type cast):

```
case class Score(score: Double, tag: String)
```

then extract all the keys from the data:

```
val keys = oldDF.rdd
    .flatMap(r => r.getMap(1).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Score]].toList)
    .collect.map(_._1).distinct.toList
```

finally you can extract all names like this:

```
def condition(keys: List[String]): Column = {
     keys match {
        case k::ks => when(col("persona_model")(k)("score").isNotNull, col("persona_model")(k)("score")).otherwise(condition(ks))
        case nil  => lit(null)
     }
 }

val newDF = oldDF.select(col("id"), condition(keys))
```

Comment: holy shit, it worked, i love u illak , just 1 more thing , it creates a table but shows score value only for those whose map key is "Tech" and null for others, can u fix it please :)

Comment: updated answer, it works only if the map only has one element (one pair key-value)